# Visual Studio 2019 .NET Forms-Notification handler already added

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a basic form app using .NET Forms but after I resize the form itself by dragging from the edges the form remains selected and everywhere I click the form gets resized. After a few clicks, I get this "Notification handler already added. Parameter name: handler" error and I can't add or move form items. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I forgot to add info about VS and .NET versions
[image]

Comment: what is kind of your project, .net framework app or .net core app? Can you describe ' I resize the form itself by dragging from the edges the form remains selected and everywhere I click the form gets resized' in more detail? If you have some code, please also provide it.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT it's a Windows Forms App (.NET CORE).

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT oh, 5 minutes passed and I can't edit the previous comment.
I mean that if I drag by one of the white squares https://prnt.sc/vcgres the form is resized. Then, if I want to click on `button1` https://prnt.sc/vcgt58 the form remains selected. Also, I can't add any more components, when I drag them on the form the crossed circle icon appears.

Comment: based on my test, I can not reproduce your problem. However, I find [.NET Core WinForms Designer softlocked when resizing forms](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1038605/net-core-winforms-designer-softlocked-when-resizin.html) is similar to your question. At the end of the article, someone said that it was fixed in the next .NET 5.0 release build.

Comment: I installed .NET 5 from here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0 but the bug is still there. My project uses .NET Core 3.1. If I close the design tab and open it again the form has the new size, I just have to do this every time I resize the form. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed in .NET 4.8.
My projects were using 4.7.